# Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot<any>'

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I was testing the code supplied in this website: [Ionic 4 Firebase CRUD](https://www.positronx.io/build-ionic-firebase-crud-app-with-angular/) and ran into a problem with the "Delete  Item from List Data" section:

```
bookingRes.snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
  this.Bookings = [];
  res.forEach(item => {
    let a = item.payload.toJSON();
    a['$key'] = item.key;
    this.Bookings.push(a as Appointment);
  })
})
```

I get an error saying "Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshot'.
  Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists'.ts(2339)".

As I understand everything is up to date

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.  This is the only answer I was able to find to avoid using toJSON which no longer exists?
`let a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.payload));`

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of these:

```
let a = JSON.parse(item.payload);
```

or

```
let a = item['payload'].toJSON();
```

Comment: No dice, the first suggestion gives "Argument of type 'DatabaseSnapshot<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)" and the second one gives the original error.

Comment: Then try to cast it: ```let a: object= item.payload.toJSON() as object;```

Comment: Sadly no, toJSON() is still causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was missing dependencies and reinstalled Firebase and angular/fire as mentioned in this thread: [Github Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1342)